# How to display different meta keys in one row in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display all meta keys with the same post ID in one row.

From:

```
ID | Meta Key | Value
123| name     | Bitcoin
123| symbol   | BTC
123| date     | April 9, 2000
123| price    | 112
124| name     | Bitcoiin
124| symbol   | B2G
124| date     | April 9, 2001
124| price    | 11
```

To:

```
ID | Name     | Symbol | Date           | Price
123| Bitcoin  | BTC    | April 9, 2000  | 112
124| Bitcoiin | B2G    | April 9, 2001  | 11
```

Tried:

```
SELECT P.ID,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS name,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'symbol', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS symbol,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'date', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS date,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'price', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS price
FROM crypto_posts AS P
LEFT JOIN crypto_postmeta AS PM on PM.post_id = P.ID
WHERE P.post_type = 'historical-info'
ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

It only outputs 1 item. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  group by

```
SELECT P.ID,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS name,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'symbol', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS symbol,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'date', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS date,
    MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'price', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS price
FROM crypto_posts AS P
LEFT JOIN crypto_postmeta AS PM on PM.post_id = P.ID
WHERE P.post_type = 'historical-info'
group by P.ID  
ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```